# Submenu with css and jquery is not showing me submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem with a code and i'm stuck, please i need some help.
Submenu is not working, when I press on the toggle button it is working and is showing me menu but i have a submenu which is not working, When i click the link. I tried a lot of stuff is css and jquery, but i'm stuck right now,

Here is how is working

```
<script async src="//jsfiddle.net/v6t3zfsk/embed/"></script>
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0uh8800g/2/)

Comment: your submenu has a css property of `display:none`, but there is absolutely nothing in your code that would change this property to something else that would make it display to the user. You need to attach a click listener to the button you want to 'open' it with and use the toggle class methods that are already in your code to toggle the menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oke I played around with it and it seems to work now. Is this the wised result?
https://jsfiddle.net/0uh8800g/3/

You had

```
 .submenu{
    display:none;
}
```

And you never told it to show.